# How to import script with relative path?

Tags: python, import, relative-path

I have the following directory structure

```
   project/
        bin/
            script
        stuff/
            __init__.py
            mainfile.py
```

Inside of script, I have the following to enable command line execution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from stuff import mainfile
```

This works, but I would have expected needing to jump up one level...

```
from ..stuff import mainfile
```

or

```
from project.stuff import mainfile
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You must be running the script from `project` directory (or have `project` directory in your pythonpath)

Comment: The relative import would only work if they were all in the same package (i.e. there was an `__init__.py` in `project`, too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually none of your examples should work out of the box.

Let's modify `bin/script.py` somewhat:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
print sys.path

from stuff import mainfile
```

This should yield something like

```
['.../project/bin', ...]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from stuff import mainfile
ImportError: No module named stuff
```

Only [the directory of the script](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) (not the current directory) is added to `sys.path` automatically:

> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, `path[0]`, **is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter.* If the script directory is not available** (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the script is read from standard input), **`path[0]` is the empty string**, which directs Python to **search modules in the current directory first**. Notice that the script directory is inserted before the entries inserted as a result of `PYTHONPATH`.

Hence there's no `stuff` module on `sys.path`. I'm not sure about your environment setup, but this is the canonical result when no additional parameters are set up (e.g. `PYTHONPATH`).

Similarily,

```
from ..stuff import mainfile
```

will result in the classic `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`. You are informed of the fact that you can only do relative imports relative to actual modules. Since inside `script` `..` does not refer to a module (because the script itself is the top level module so to say), a relative import does not work here. In a manner of speaking from Python's perspective, there is no module above the script and thus `..` does not refer to something tangible when used in the context of the script.

Note that this also means that it does *not* help to only make `project` and `project/bin` into modules themselves by dropping `__init__.py` marker files. Relative imports to a *parent* of the script are only possible if the parent of the script is actually something python has a concept of.

This is one of the reasons, why the `-m` command line switch exists making it possible to run a module from the command line. For example, given the above relative import

```
python -m project.bin.script
```

does the trick, but only if executed from the proper directory (*projectdir*/..).

That problem is even worse with

```
from project.stuff import mainfile
```

because the `project` directory is only automatically on `sys.path` when you start a script from the directory above `project` *and* do not specify a main script to run:

```
cd <projectdir>/..
python -m project.bin.script
# works
cd <projectdir>
python -m bin.script
# does not work, because `sys.path` starts with <projectdir>
# and it's `stuff.mainfile` now, not `project.stuff.mainfile`.
```

If you want to import modules from `project` in your script, fix up `sys.path` to your needs:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(sys.path[0]))
from stuff import mainfile
```

Comment: This is a very thorough answer but it doesn't explain why it works as is.  I tested the file by cloning it into a test directory and executing the script at the command line, and it works without issue... leaving me very confused.

Comment: I have no idea why it works for you as it clearly shouldn't without additional setup. Do you have anything on `PYTHONPATH`? Maybe your distribution automatically sets `PYTHONPATH=.` (for whatever reason). Note that just printing `sys.path` in `script` might shed some light, too.

Comment: I wonder if my setup.py file has anything to do with it?  I'm pretty green with packaging / distribution... I'll mark this as correct and do some digging as you suggest later.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first add the parent directory into `sys.path`. Try the following:

```
# This is a file in bin/ directory.
this_file_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(this_file_path, '..'))
import stuff.mainfile
```